# Why mousehover don't work in this Jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a attribute to body when users hover by a dropdown selector.
This is my code.

```
<select id="pa_cor" class="" name="attribute_pa_cor" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_cor" "="" data-show_option_none="yes" >
    <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
    <option value="cinza" class="attached enabled">Cinza</option>
    <option value="rosa" class="attached enabled">Rosa</option>
    <option value="verde" class="attached enabled">Verde</option>
    <option value="vermelho" class="attached enabled">Vermelho</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('#pa_cor').change(function() {
    $('body').attr('produto', $(this).val());
});


// trigger the change event
$('#pa_cor').trigger('change');
```

I tried to change the `change(function()` to `mousehover(function()` and `hover(function()` but they didn't work.

Can anyone help?
If necessary I can send printscreen that I'm trying to use the codes.

Comment: It's `mouseover` not `mousehover`... Also, what is this `"=""`?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting in your browser console?

Comment: My site: https://3brow.com/produto/camiseta-tigre/ - when you change the "Cores" dropdown, add a atribute to body - E.g produto=blue - but when you hover by dropdown selectors, nothing happens.

Comment: I guess you want the `mouseover` event to trigger when you're over an `option` and they don't generally trigger events.. Bad support for IE too..

Comment: Yes, the change event works, but mousehover, hover, over, on('mouseover, on('mousehover, don't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$( "#pa_cor" ).hover(function() {
    // code
});
```

or:

```
$( "#pa_cor" ).on("mouseover", function () {
    // code
});
```

When you say:

> when users hover by a dropdown selector

I assume you mean hover over the Select Drop Down?

Comment: And I guess he want to get the value of the `option` attribute.

Comment: So they did, also try `.on("mouseover"` too! Updated.

Comment: I tried, did not work. After I put your code the "click" stopped to work. I removed it to work again. Sorry my english. Can you help?

Answer (score -3):

Try this.

```
$('#pa_cor').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
})
```

Comment: i guess i didn't understand the question. Can you please tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: My site: 3brow.com/produto/camiseta-tigre - when you change the "Cores" dropdown, add a atribute to body - E.g produto=blue - but when you hover by dropdown selectors, nothing happens.